# Shared data storage between mobile and wear app

Tags: android, sqlite, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I am building an android app that has a **mobile**, **wear** and **shared** module. It is an app that stores data with my **SampleObject** to the **SQLiteDatabase**.

```
SampleObject{
     long ID; // Primary key, autoincrement
     Date date;
     String text;
}
```

All methods regarding users list of SampleObjects are in the shared module. Both mobile and wear can insert, edit and delete objects.

Is there a way to use "shared" database or do I have to use separate DBs for mobile and wear and on wear connect to compare them and merge?

If I have to use separate DBs, what is the best way (and when) to compare them (there can be some deleted items that are still contained in one of DBs)?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like that -> https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/ . If not just ignore me :)

Comment: Yes, I would use WearableListenerService, but my question is if there is some shared DB, if not, when to use data sharing and compare DBs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no shared SQLite database. If your shared data requirements are simple enough to store in `SharedPreferences`, you could use [PrefSyncService](https://github.com/StringMon/prefsyncservice), but I've never seen a similar library for syncing SQL data.

In general, though, I would think that the question of when to sync them is going to be driven by your own app logic; there's no "one size fits all" answer for that.